# Why is drop shadow offset to the left?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to create a drop shadow on a div that is compatible with IE 7 & 8. I only want the drop shadow to appear below the div (not on the top, left, or right borders). Using `DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow()` I am setting the X offset to 0 but the drop shadow still appears on the left border of my div in IE 7 & 8 only. Any ideas why?

```css
#Container {
background-color: white;
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
width: auto;
zoom:1; 
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='grey', OffX=0, OffY=5, Strength=5);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px grey;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px grey;
box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px grey;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you blur an image, it gets larger. Even if you offset `0px` on the horizontal axis (as you are doing), the larger blur will appear past the left of your content.

Comment: Thank you. Does that mean that I cannot somehow only show the drop shadow on the bottom border? If I can only move the shadow horizontally and vertically I'm not clear how that can be accomplished.

Comment: I think I am using the wrong filter altogether. I should be using DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(). Yes? However this will not create the blurred effect.